# Error on claiming tokens

Tags: metamask

was wondering maybe someone can help with this one.

I'm trying to claim my tokens on Pinnksale after a presale.
So, the problem is, every time I click on the CLAIM Button--- the metamask wallet gives me this message.

```
 " This transaction is expected to fail. Trying to execute it is expected to be expensive but fail, and is not recommended."
```

Does anyone know how to fix it ???

thanks)

Answer (score 1):

[From this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/119496/96624) by Lauri

> What probably happens is that Metamask runs a static call to the
> contract with the same parameters, to simulate what would happen if
> the transaction took place. If it notices that the static call
> reverts, it gives you this error - because most likely the real
> transaction would revert as well.
>
> So most likely there is something in the code which causes a revert
> with the given parameters.